# Typing on an Android Device straight from computer?

Tags: android, adb

Can you use ADB to type directly on an android device from a computer? If so, how?

Comment: Something to take into account for chars not supported by `inout`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14273689/236465

Answer (score 33):

Although this question is rather old, I'd like to add this answer:

You may use `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE` resp. `adb shell input text "mytext"`. A list of all keycodes can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)

Comment: You can also use `adb shell input text "text"`, where the text can contain `%s` to represent spaces.

Answer (score 9):

As Manuel said, you can use `adb shell input text`, but you need to replace spaces with `%s`, as well as handle quotes. Here's a simple bash script to make that very easy:

```
#!/bin/bash

text=$(printf '%s%%s' ${@})  # concatenate and replace spaces with %s
text=${text%%%s}  # remove the trailing %s
text=${text//\'/\\\'}  # escape single quotes
text=${text//\"/\\\"}  # escape double quotes
# echo "[$text]"  # debugging

adb shell input text "$text"
```

Save as, say, `atext` and make executable. Then you can invoke the script without quotes...

```
atext Hello world!
```

...unless you need to send quotes, in which case you do need to put them between the other type of quotes (this is a shell limitation):

```
atext "I'd" like it '"shaken, not stirred"'
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, though I had to put similar lines in the script to escape things like semicolons and ampersands.

Comment: I made a Ruby REPL so you can type freely without worrying about shell escaping: https://gist.github.com/Pistos/0bf26f46c04bc43cc95c224d264e9f39

Comment: You can also do something like,
```lang-bsh
#!/bin/bash

escape_text()
{
   printf '%s' "$1" | sed -e 's/[]['\''\"&;()|$]/\\&/g'
}

text=$(printf '%s%%s' ${@})  # concatenate and replace spaces with %s
text=${text%%%s}  # remove the trailing %s
text=$(escape_text "$text")
echo "Text = $text" # debugging
```

Answer (score 5):

To avoid expansion/evaluation of the text parameter (i.e. for special characters like '$' or ';'), you could wrap them into quotes like this:

```
adb shell "input text 'insert your text here'"
```

Comment: this is not working for me. The following (as suggested above) works    adb shell input text "insert%syour%stext%shere"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `Bash`-based solution that works for *arbitrary/complex strings* (e.g. random passwords). The other solutions presented here all failed for me in that regard:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -r -p "Enter string: " string    # prompt user to input string
string="${string// /%s}"              # replace spaces in string with '%s'
printf -v string "%q" "${string}"     # quote string in a way that allows it to be reused as shell input
adb shell input text "${string}"      # input string on device via adb
```

The following code may be used for repeated/continuous input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo
echo "Hit CTRL+D or CTRL+C to exit."
echo
while true; do
    read -r -p "Enter string: " string || { echo "^D"; break; }
    string="${string// /%s}"
    printf -v string "%q" "${string}"
    echo "Sending string via adb..."
    adb shell input text "${string}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

`input` does not support UTF-8 or other encodings, you will see something like this if you try it

```
$ adb shell input text ö
Killed
```

therefore if these are your intention you need something more robust.

The following script uses [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) with [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) backend to avoid `input` limitations.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(), useuiautomatorhelper=True)

oid = vc.uiAutomatorHelper.ui_device.find_object(clazz='android.widget.EditText').oid
vc.uiAutomatorHelper.ui_object2.set_text(oid, '你好世界 ')
```

it finds an `EditText` and then enters some Chinese characters and a emoji.

You can achieve the same using `bash` and `curl` if entering text is the only you need.

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# simple-input-text
# - Finds an EditText
# - Enters text
#
# prerequisites:
# - adb finds and lists the device
# - ./culebratester2 start-server
# - jq installed (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
#

set -e
set +x

base_url=http://localhost:9987/v2/

do_curl() {
    curl -sf -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "$@"
}

oid=$(do_curl -X POST "${base_url}/uiDevice/findObject" \
    -d "{'clazz': 'android.widget.EditText'}" | jq .oid)

do_curl -X POST "${base_url}/uiObject2/${oid}/setText" \
    -d "{'text': '你好世界 '}"
```

Answer (score 0):

When using zsh, here is a more robust function to feed text to Android:

```
function adbtext() {
    while read -r line; do
        adb shell input text ${(q)${line// /%s}}
    done
}
```

While Zsh quoting may be slightly different from a regular POSIX shell, I didn't find anything it wouldn't work on. Dan's answer is missing for example `>` which also needs to be escaped.

I am using it with `pass show ... | adbtext`.