# How to turn off Wifi via ADB?

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-wifi

Im automating a testing procedure for wifi calling and I was wondering is there a way to turn off/on wifi via adb?

I would either like to disable/enable wifi or kill wifi calling (com.movial.wificall) and restart it.

Is it possible to do this all via adb and shell commands?

so far I have found:

```
android.net.wifi.WifiManager
setWifiEnabled(true/false)
```

Im just not sure how to put it together

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kamleshkarwande/92a2421ee3f1881ed10d59949b6a4e4d

Answer (score 109, accepted):

## Using "svc" through ADB (rooted required):

**Enable:**

```
adb shell su -c 'svc wifi enable'
```

**Disable:**

```
adb shell su -c 'svc wifi disable'
```

## Using Key Events through ADB:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings
adb shell input keyevent 20 & adb shell input keyevent 23
```

The first line launch "wifi.WifiSettings" activity which open the WiFi Settings page. The second line simulate key presses.

I tested those two lines on a Droid X. But Key Events above probably need to edit in other devices because of different Settings layout.

More info about "keyevents" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events).

Comment: Thank you very much for the post. Its not quite the same on my phone, but since you posted the input events I figured out it is key events 19 and 23. Thanks Again. : )

Comment: Ok you got it? Yeah I tested that on a Droid X, I wasn't sure what phone you had :)

Comment: In my opinion answer by Berkk is much better (notably less hacky).

Comment: to use those keyevents to toggle wifi in Android 5.0 you would probably have to hit different events then in answer. I would say `adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 23` (the first one can be 20 as well) - this is working if there is no option selected when you enter the wifi settings screen (if there is, you should skip the first event)

Comment: I answered this over 2 years ago. It was just an example to help someone automate a task.

Comment: adb shell svc wifi enable/disable. 
Also just realised there where several comments about this in Berkk's answer, my bad.

Comment: svc wifi enable/disable works only for rooted devices. The other way of automating by using keyevent won't work across all androids.

Comment: @ThejusKrishna See the date above. I posted this answer over 3 years ago with minor edits. If you want to make an edit you can. Please learn how to use Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please don't feel offended. This answer makes no sense across all the android phones. Better answer was found below and definitely feel this is outdated.

Comment: it required `su` here like @IvanMorgillo said `adb shell su -c 'svc wifi disable'`

Comment: i tried to disable the wifi and got: `sh: resetreason: can't execute: Permission denied` how should i get permissions? the phone wasn't locked either

Comment: Doesn't work on my device. I have full root. No errors, no output. Network stays connected, no change in the device settings still shows wifi on and connected.

Comment: These commands: adb shell "su 0 svc wifi enable" / adb shell "su 0 svc wifi disable  to enable/disable wifi respectively worked for me

Answer (score 83):

I was searching for the same to turn bluetooth on/off, and I found this:

```
adb shell svc wifi enable|disable
```

Comment: I've tried using this code on 6 different devices ranging from Gingerbread to JellyBean, rooted to non-rooted and I couldn't get it to work on any of them. What devices are you able to get this to work on?

Comment: @Nefarii - for this I needed to request adb shell into the device.....then request su permission....then I was able to run these commands properly.

Comment: Works on rooted Sony Ericsson Xperia and Motorola Razr

Comment: Working on rooted Nexus 5, 4.4.2: adb shell su -c "svc wifi disable"

Comment: this works on my Samsung S8 non-rooted, the `adb shell su -c 'svc wifi enable'` didn't (since it wasn't rooted)

Comment: Works on a non-rooted Pixel 4a with Android 11. ( Attached via USB, Developer mode on).

Comment: Works on Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra running non-rooted stock Android 11 image

Comment: Works on a Zebra TC26 device - Android 10 (non rooted)

Answer (score 26):

Simple way to switch wifi on non-rooted devices is to use simple app:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WifiManager wfm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        try {
            wfm.setWifiEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(getIntent().getStringExtra("wifi")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

ADB commands:

```
$ adb shell am start -n org.mytools.config/.MainActivity -e wifi true
$ adb shell am start -n org.mytools.config/.MainActivity -e wifi false
```

Comment: I tweaked this a little bit and changed the activity for a BroadcastReceiver so it can be added to any app and It won't show any GUI.

Comment: @ferdy182: Can you please post the code so that others may use and evaluate it?

Comment: @GodMan find it here https://plus.google.com/110502863648146989289/posts/Ri1Dcm6cn48

Comment: Do we need to make any change for android N?

Comment: i used below command on samsung s5 , but it has not enabled any wifi  adb  -s 4d0075754fdb41cd shell  am start -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings  wifi True

Comment: You have create an apk with the above code for this. @pankajmishra

Comment: @GodMan can you please post that apk again?

Answer (score 17):

#### Via cmd command on Android 11 & 12 (no-root-required)

enable Wi-Fi (turn on):

```
adb shell cmd -w wifi set-wifi-enabled enabled
```

disable Wi-Fi (turn off):

```
adb shell cmd -w wifi set-wifi-enabled disabled
```

Comment: the command returns the `Invalid args for set-wifi-enabled: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected 'enabled' or 'disabled' as next arg but got 'disable'`/ [...] `but got 'enable'` error if running `enable` / `disable` instead of `enabled` / `disabled`.

Comment: Thank you for correcting this. Will fix it on my wiki immediately as well.

Comment: cool, works perfectly for me! (Galaxy Tab A7, Android 11)

Answer (score 7):

1. go to location `android/android-sdk/platform-tools`
2. <kbd>shift</kbd>+right click
3. open cmd here and type the following commands

   1. `adb shell`
   2. `su`
   3. `svc wifi enable/disable`
4. done!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

I tested this command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings
adb shell input keyevent 19 && adb shell input keyevent 19 && adb shell input keyevent 23
```

and only works on window's prompt, maybe because of some driver

The `adb shell svc wifi enable|disable` solution only works with root permissions.

Comment: This was particularly useful: my Genymotion emulators randomly start up with the wifi available but sometimes not selected. I used this:  shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings; input keyevent 20; input keyevent 23'

Answer (score 3):

It will work if you use with quotes:

```
adb shell "svc wifi enable"
```

Comment: I still cant get this too work, Ive tried it on the Note, Note2, a rooted GS3, and an Amaze.

Comment: if you try this in a command prompt it will work..
It will not open anything.. the action will be performed in background

Comment: im able to run this without quotes too

Answer (score 2):

I can just do:

```
settings put global wifi_on 0
settings put global wifi_scan_always_enabled 0
```

Sometimes, if done during boot (i.e. to fix [bootloop such as this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2507778)), it doesn't apply well and you can proceed also enabling airplane mode first:

```
settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
settings put global wifi_on 0
settings put global wifi_scan_always_enabled 0
```

Other option is to force this with:

```
while true; do settings put global wifi_on 0; done
```

Tested in Android 7 on LG G5 (SE) with (unrooted) stock mod.

Answer (score 1):

All these `input keyevent` combinations are SO android/hardware dependent, it's a pain.

However, I finally found the combination for my old android 4.1 device :

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings
adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method **doesn't require root** and should work anywhere (according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean)), even on Android Q+, if you keep `targetSdkVersion = 28`).

1. Make a blank app.
2. Create a `ContentProvider`:

   ```
   class ApiProvider : ContentProvider() {

       private val wifiManager: WifiManager? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
           requireContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager?
       }

       private fun requireContext() = checkNotNull(context)

       private val matcher = UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH).apply {
           addURI("wifi", "enable", 0)
           addURI("wifi", "disable", 1)
       }

       override fun query(uri: Uri, projection: Array<out String>?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<out String>?, sortOrder: String?): Cursor? {
           when (matcher.match(uri)) {
               0 -> {
                   enforceAdb()
                   withClearCallingIdentity {
                       wifiManager?.isWifiEnabled = true
                   }
               }
               1 -> {
                   enforceAdb()
                   withClearCallingIdentity {
                       wifiManager?.isWifiEnabled = false
                   }
               }
           }
           return null
       }

       private fun enforceAdb() {
           val callingUid = Binder.getCallingUid()
           if (callingUid != 2000 && callingUid != 0) {
               throw SecurityException("Only shell or root allowed.")
           }
       }

       private inline fun <T> withClearCallingIdentity(block: () -> T): T {
           val token = Binder.clearCallingIdentity()
           try {
               return block()
           } finally {
               Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(token)
           }
       }

       override fun onCreate(): Boolean = true

       override fun insert(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues?): Uri? = null

       override fun update(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<out String>?): Int = 0

       override fun delete(uri: Uri, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<out String>?): Int = 0

       override fun getType(uri: Uri): String? = null
   }
   ```
3. Declare it in `AndroidManifest.xml` along with necessary permission:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

   <application>

       <provider
           android:name=".ApiProvider"
           android:authorities="wifi"
           android:exported="true" />
   </application>
   ```
4. Build the app and install it.
5. Call from ADB:

   ```
   adb shell content query --uri content://wifi/enable
   adb shell content query --uri content://wifi/disable
   ```
6. Make a batch script/shell function/shell alias with a short name that calls these commands.

Depending on your device you may need additional permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This works as of android 7.1.1, non-rooted

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings && adb shell input keyevent 23 && adb shell input keyevent 23
```

This will launch the activity and then send the DPAD center keyevent.  I added another DPAD center as an experiment to see if you can enable it in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

**`ADB Connect to wifi with credentials :`**

You can use the following ADB command to connect to wifi and enter password as well :

adb wait-for-device shell am start -n com.android.settingstest/.wifi.WifiSettings -e WIFI 1 -e AccessPointName "enter_user_name" -e Password "enter_password"

Answer (score 0):

In Android tests I'm doing as follows:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("svc wifi **enable**")
```

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("svc wifi **disable**")
```