# Use ADB to check if Airplane mode is turned on?

Tags: android, adb

I know that we can do the following:

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS
adb shell input keyevent 19 ; adb shell input keyevent 23
```

to turn on/off airplane mode on android device.

However, is there anyway to check if currently the device has airplane mode turned on through ADB ?

I'm asking this because the two lines of code above will toggle airplane mode without knowing whether it is turning it on or off. But I need a way to make sure that airplane mode is indeed on/off through ADB.

Please help me out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: For a specific device, there seem to be useful changes exposed by running a diff on the output of `adb shell getprop` in both conditions - for example with the network carrier name - however it may be hard to write general rules across all devices/versions.  But since you are talking ADB, perhaps you are talking about an automated test run on a limited collection of devices, for which you could determine a workable set of pragmatic checks.  It's also possible that you'd get a false report if airplane mode is not active but the device has for some reason momentarily failed to find service.

Comment: I would say that Anand's answer should be accepted instead since the command in Alex's answer just changes the Airplane mode setting value (button state), but without any real effect (networks are still enabled). You have to broadcast the intent after the setting change to have the same effect as manually tapping the Airplane mode button on the device.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`adb shell settings get global airplane_mode_on` returns `0` for airplane_mode off and `1` for airplane_mode on.

Comment: Thank you very much ! A quick question, do you know where I can find out more about this adb shell settings ? I mean what are some of the other things I can query ? Can I do something like "adb shell settings get global wifi_on" to check if wifi is turned on ? Is there any documentation on this on the web ? Sorry if this has a really obvious answer that I'm not seeing.

Comment: `settings get` command is just a simple java wrapper for "settings" content provider query. and as usual it is with android - the best documentation is in the source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/settings/src/com/android/commands/settings/SettingsCmd.java

Answer (score 17):

You can use the following commands after doing adb shell.

**Turn on:**
`adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1`
`adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true`

**Turn off:**
`adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0`
`adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false`

This will make airplane mode ON/OFF

Comment: It looks like that you can omit the `--ez` parameter, so the broadcast command will be same for both enabling and disabling: `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE`. Could you explain a bit how exactly does it work, please? I mean why are both commands needed? The first one just changes the Airplane mode setting, but without a real effect on networks, the second one does the rest of work.

Comment: This will work on Android 6 (and below) only.


From Nougat (Android 7), it raises `Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE`