# Turning airplane mode on via ADB(Android 4.1 or earlier)

Tags: android, adb

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2)
 and I tried as follows :

```
settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true
```

It works really well on Android 4.4.1

but does not work in 4.0.1. (settings: not found / It supports version 4.2 or higher.)

So, i tried again [as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506591/turning-airplane-mode-on-via-adb) :

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS
adb shell input keyevent 19
adb shell input keyevent 23
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

Also, this work is strange

"AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS" Window Popup -> Focus on Airplane Mode (no check) -> Volume up........

And it is turned off the screen, does not work

So I think that this way is not good.

**Q** : How to work like a 'settings put global airplane_mode_on 1' in 4.1 or earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AIRPLANE_MODE_ON` used to belong to `system` namespace before they moved it to `global`. So the old settings command would have been `settings put system airplane_mode_on 1`. But since the `settings` command is not available in your build you can just modify the value directly in the database instead:

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "update system set value='1' where name='airplane_mode_on';"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried on Android 4.0.1 but I can not find the binary 'settings'. [New command-line binary 'settings' shipping with Android 4.2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/tip-command-line-binary-settings-t2180945)

Comment: `settings` command is just a wrapper for the `content://settings` content provider. you can just modify the value directly in the database

Comment: Editing the value in 2.3.3 has no effect on having internet access or not. I still could access the internet with the value set to 1 or 0.

Comment: @polym You have to broadcast the intent after the setting change as described in the OP's question.