# Best way to turn airplane mode on and off with Calabash

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

What is the best way to turn airplane mode on and off using calabash-android?

Can I use `perform_action('set_preferences', .... )` ??

What does set_preferences do above? I would like to set up android settings during test of application.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. Is it for simulator or device?

In case you just need to disable wifi, you could use

```
def disable_network
%x(adb shell svc wifi disable)
end


def enable_network
%x(adb shell svc wifi enable)
end
```

Found here https://azevedorafaela.wordpress.com/tag/disable-wifi-android-simulator-calabash/
I have not tried it myself though.

Comment: How can I get a list of all the settings I can set with ADB? I would like to set up the device with Android settings and run tests. Example : Change the language and run all the tests, Change to Airplane mode and run tests, Change to (insert an Android setting here) .... ?

Comment: Good question I have not tried that myself. But you will probably need to use something like "adb shell ..." to do it. So try and search for items related to that.

Answer (score 2):

For Android devices, we can use this code in Step definition to forget Wi-Fi which is connected:

do

```
%x(adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings)
%x(adb shell input keyevent 20)
%x(adb shell input keyevent 23)
%x(adb shell input keyevent 20)
%x(adb shell input keyevent 23)
```

end