# Airplane mode simulation on a real Android device with calabash-android

Tags: android, wifi, adb, calabash-android, airplane-mode

In part of my testing I’m checking if my app can handle returning from airplane mode to normal mode.

Looking for a process that enable/disable airplane mode on real Android device.

All I found is how to enable/disable WiFi and data on simulator here - [Best way to turn airplane mode on and off with Calabash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132994/best-way-to-turn-airplane-mode-on-and-off-with-calabash/27228962#27228962).
Tried to run those commands on my real device (LG G3 – Android 5.0) and nothing happened.

Looking on my services list on my device (`adb shell service list`) but cannot find airplane.

I understand that changing to airplane mode is disabling the data/WiFi/Bluetooth/GPS

Is there a way to enable airplane mode on real device?
Or even just the data/WiFi (enough for my testing)?

Comment: Do you have root permissions on your device?

Comment: I can't do that. This automation is going to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no luck with adb commands,
You can enable/disable airplane mode with `adb shell input` gestures.

```
  adb -s <DeviceSerialNumber> shell input touchscreen swipe x1 y1 x2 y2 time
```

Where `x1,x2,y1,x2` is swipe start and end coordinates and `time` is time in ms to perform the gesture.

By combining these, you can perform anything on screen.

For example airplane mode.

- Get screen resolution of your device
- Swipe notification bar from the top
- Touch airplane mode
- And press back button

Not the best way to do that, but comes handy sometimes.

Another way around that

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html

Check the settings you interested in, and use
`adb shell settings put`

For example:

```
  adb -s <DeviceSerialNumber> shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
```

A question about events:

[How to use ADB to send touch events to device using sendevent command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437686/how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command)