# ADB command to enable or disable sim card?(Rooted)

Tags: android, adb

is there any adb command to enable and disable my sim card(primary sim)?
you can enable/disable WiFi,mobile data etc but couldn't find adb command to enable or disable sim card.

Comment: maybe try android stackexchange? this doesnt look programming related..https://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think so it's not possible to control sim/sim slot from ADB, you can check for is there any shell script command available for doing this. Or you can try with controlling Aeroplan mode from adb command, please refer below link for changing Aeroplan mode from ADB. 
[Turning airplane mode on via ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506591/turning-airplane-mode-on-via-adb)

Comment: i want the wifi enabled so i cant use airplane mode since it will also disable wifi