# Turning airplane mode on via ADB (android 7)

Tags: android, adb, android-7.0-nougat

I know this question has allready been answered like in [Turning airplane mode on via ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506591/turning-airplane-mode-on-via-adb).
However, with Android 7 (Nougat) and above the suggested methode doesn't work. I get following error.

[image]

Is there a workaround for this?

Does this effect the broadcasting over adb for Android Nougat in generall?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED) it seems you can't :

> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Answer (score 0):

I created a script for Noughat. Works on Samsung. Have to test on others.

`#!/bin/bash`

`adb -s $1 shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS`

`sleep 5`
`adb -s $1 shell input tap 100 750`
`sleep 2`

`adb -s $1 shell input keyevent 21`

`adb -s $1 shell input keyevent 21`

`sleep 2`

`adb -s $1 shell input keyevent 22`

`sleep 5`

`adb -s $1 shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER`

`sleep 5`

`adb -s $1 shell input keyevent 4`

`sleep 5`

Comment: This is just a work around solution.

Answer (score 0):

I put this in a script on my OnePlus 5 running Nougat (Android 7.1) and it turns on Airplane Mode

```
input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP;
sleep 0.5;
input keyevent KEYCODE_MOVE_HOME;
am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS;
sleep 0.5;
input tap 100 350;
sleep 1;     
input keyevent 4;
```