# How to turn WIFI & 3G on/off on Android device - from Windows OS (using the CMD)

Tags: android, shell, command-line, android-intent, command

I have the following command to run on CMD

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS
```

Now with this I go into the *'Wireless & Networks'* of the connected device. Can anyone tell me how to disable & enable WIFI from the **COMMAND-PROMPT**?

The same needs to be done for 3G also.

Reason to do this from CMD : I am trying some android automation.

Comment: Please see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033757/turn-off-wifi-via-adb) for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a little, I have created 2-android apps.

One to enable/disable wifi; and other for 3G(or data).

Now everytime i call this App from CMD, the wifi or 3G can be controlled. ;)

I am still looking out for the easier approach..... directly from CMD.