# Switching off wifi on android application using appium dot net driver

Tags: c#, android, appium

I am using appium dot net driver and I want to switch off/on the wifi . Please suggest method  in c# using appium or adb command that can be send to device to switch off wifi

Answer (score 0):

From question [How to turn off Wifi via ADB?:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033757/how-to-turn-off-wifi-via-adb)

**Enable Wi-Fi:**

```
adb shell svc wifi enable
```

**Disable Wi-Fi:**

```
adb shell svc wifi disable
```

---

From question [Run Command Prompt Commands:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C adb shell svc wifi enable/disable";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

**Note:** I don't know C#, so correct me if something is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In C#, I am not sure about direct method, but you can try this:

To Disable WIFI:

```
((AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>)appiumDriver).ConnectionType = ConnectionType.AirplaneMode;
```

To Enable WIFI:

```
((AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>)appiumDriver).ConnectionType = ConnectionType.AllNetworkOn;
```

Comment: Not sure if this answer is valid anymore -- throws error `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command ''C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe' -P 5037 -s 19025D8359 shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE from pid=29791, uid=2000`