# How to test wifi connection via adb?

Tags: android, shell, automation, adb, android-wifi

Im automating wifi off/on via adb.

I would either like to disable/enable wifi based on the test case

so far I have found good information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033757/how-to-turn-off-wifi-via-adb)

However I want to test the connection before executing following command

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n         com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 23
```

Above command disables wifi if enabled, enables wifi if disabled. I want to first test the connection and take action if required. I am wondering if there is a way to do using adb command. This can be achieved programatically but I want it to be done through adb for making it more reliable.

Also following command works only if device is rooted

```
adb shell "svc wifi enable"
```

Also following command launches test on screen but provides no info via adb

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiStatusTest
```

Answer (score 20):

To know everything about Wifi status of the device:

```
adb shell dumpsys wifi
```

To just know whether it's enabled or not:

```
adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep "Wi-Fi is"
```

To know more detailed status:

```
adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep "mNetworkInfo"
```

1. If connected to a valid network, it shows
   ***"CONNECTED/CONNECTED"***. It also shows the name of the connected network.
2. If wifi has been enabled but it is yet to connect to a network, it shows ***"DISCONNECTED/SCANNING"***.
3. If wifi is disabled, it shows ***"DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED"***.

Comment: Android O onwards.  adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep "curState"  will give following 3 otputs dpending upon state    1. "InitialState" : if Wifi is off. 2. "DisconnectedState" if wifi is on but disconnected  , 3. "ConnectedState": if device connected to network.

Comment: Will this work, if I use those commands in Java, using Process and Runtime for example?

Comment: adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep "mNetworkInfo" is not working with Android 11. do we have any alternatives?

Answer (score 15):

Below command will give you the internet status and connectivity mode(cellular or Wi-Fi)

```
adb shell dumpsys connectivity
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to determine whether or not WiFi is turned on you can run `adb shell settings get global wifi_on` which returns 1 if it's on and 0 if it's off.

If you have multiple devices connected you can run `adb -s [UDID_HERE] shell settings get global wifi_on` to get the WiFi status of an individual phone. To find the UDID you can run `adb devices`.

Answer (score 4):

This would only tell you if there is internet access but you can do:

```
adb shell ping www.google.com
```

Comment: But this does not work on my Sony Xperia device. This command gives no information.

Comment: don't you get something after typing this?

Comment: Nope. However I am able to connect to internet on device

Comment: Well, I'm sorry it doesn't work, I'll try to find sth else

Answer (score 3):

```
adb shell dumpsys wifi | sed -n '1p'
```

is faster and safer than

```
adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep "Wi-Fi is"
```

because the output of `dumpsys wifi` contains the system logs that may have been contaminated by other applications

Comment: The command line "dumpsys wifi" works for me. But be aware, in my case, I found on one android device the "Wi-Fi is enabled" is at the first line, while on another phone, such output is NOT at the first line, so I think `grep "Wi-Fi is"` is the better apporach.

Answer (score 0):

[Atish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658566) was working fine until Android 11/R. For this OS onwards, I recommend using Abhishek's suggestion:

```
adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep "curState=ConnectedState"
```

Answer (score -1):

Not perfect, but you could dump UI layout and then search for ON/OFF text like this (bash):

```
adb pull $(adb shell uiautomator dump | grep -o '[^ ]*.xml') ui.xml
grep 'text="OFF"' ui.xml
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  # Turn WIFI on
fi
```