# Enable/Disable wifi using Xamarin UiTest

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I try to enable/disable wifi programmatically within my Xamarin Ui Test.
I already found this: [Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically). But it seems not to work within the UiTest.

I also tried something like this:

```
Context appContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
var wifiManager = (WifiManager)appContext.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
bool status = false;
wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(status);
```

The first line (Android.App.Application.Context) throws an exception:

```
Message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm using following namespaces:

```
using Android.Net.Wifi;
using Android.Content;
```

My project has a reference to `Mono.Android`.

Comment: Add that as method within your `Xamarin.Android` project and expose it as a backdoor that you can call via UITest code.

Answer (score 4):

The backdoor approach works fine for me.

The solution that works for me was a combination of:

- [Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-backdoors
- Some small own changes (for appcontext/context). Just context did not work for me.

1.: Add following line to the AndroidManifest.xml file of the Android project:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

2.: Add following lines to the MainActivity.cs of the Android project:

```
using Java.Interop;
using Android.Net.Wifi;

[Export("ChangeWifiState")]
public void ChangeWifiState(bool state)
{
    Context appContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
    var wifiManager = (WifiManager)appContext.GetSystemService(WifiService);
    wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(state);
}
```

3.: Call following method out of the Xamarin Ui Test:

```
app.Invoke("ChangeWifiState", false);    // true to enable wifi, false to disable wifi
```

PS: I use Xamarin Forms. I've got four different projects: a core project, an Android project, a Ui project, and a test project.

I just found **a second solution without using the actual** app.
It uses ADB commands to enable/disable wifi:

```
        var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/C adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 23 & adb shell input keyevent 82 & adb shell input tap 500 1000"
        };
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

This can be used without a rooted device :). 
Steps explained:
`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings` opens the wifi settings.
`adb shell input keyevent 23` enables/disables wifi.
I'm not sure why the command `adb shell input keyevent 19` is used, but it works.
`adb shell input keyevent 82` clicks the menu button to change back to the original app.
`adb shell input tap 500 1000` clicks the coordinate x=500, y=1000 (center of screen).This may need be changed for different solutions.
Sources for this solution:

- [How to turn off Wifi via ADB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033757/how-to-turn-off-wifi-via-adb)
- [ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)
- [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: For some reasons, this solution didn't work anymore correctly for my new Android 8.1.<br>
Therefore I changed two things:<br>
1. Replace the "keyevent 82" by the coordinates of the menu button (Maybe security update of 8.1)<br>
2. Split the big Argument into 3 small ones (1: Open settings, 2: Change status, 3: Return to original app)

Comment: Franklin84 - Is it possible to invoke setting app through my app then change the network. Looks like it's not possible.