# Android shell su doesn't have option -c

Tags: android

I compiled Android 8.1 from source code.

```
$ adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release 
8.1.0

$ adb shell
angler:/ $ su -c date
su: invalid uid/gid '-c'
1|angler:/ $ su --help
usage: su [UID[,GID[,GID2]...]] [COMMAND [ARG...]]

Switch to WHO (default 'root') and run the given command (default sh).

where WHO is a comma-separated list of user, group,
and supplementary groups in that order.
```

Various resources, including https://stackoverflow.com/a/10038568/746461, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201680/97993, seem to indicate `su` has option `-c`. However my android doens't have.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android `su` never had the `-c` option. All sources suggesting to use `su -c` are meant to be used with third-party `su` binaries from packages like `SuperSU`.

The Android version of `su` does not need `-c` because it is the default option.