# Activate/unlock phone via adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

Using the adb shell I can input text on the phone. But that does not work, if the phone's display is off. I have to press the home button first and unlock the screen for this to work. How can I automate this with the adb shell without adding additional code on the device?

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME
```

Unfortunately, that does not work at all.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=865876
Looks like it may work, have not tried it yet.

Comment: @brett Thanks brett, it would be nice if this can be done without additional code (edited my question). But I am afraid this is not possible.

Comment: You could always reboot the phone , would do the trick but you'd have to wait....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `adb shell input keyevent 26` to wake up the device. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)) Now do the text input or whatsoever you want to do. And, unlocking can also be done using `input` command but different locks requires different technique, so you'll have to Google a bit, or provide the info here so that I/others can answer it.

The same command can put the device to sleep as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the display power state with `dumpsys power` and then if needed emulate the power key press to wake it up.