# Push android application to background

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to push an application to the background through an adb command? I have an application which calls google navigation and I want push google navigation to the background using an adb command. I don't want to just go back to the home screen, I want make sure the app which called google navigation remains on the foreground. So far I have:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.google.android.apps.maps
```

But the above command force stops the process instead of pushing to background.

Comment: Um, why not just bring your application back to the foreground, by calling `startActivity()` on one of its activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CommonWare commented, Instead pushing the other app to background you can bring your app to foreground by calling startactivity and by setting appropriate flags.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I had to change Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK since I was calling it from a non activity class.

Comment: I have no app. I just want to push another app from adb to the background, I don't care what gets into the foreground as long as it's a different one. Any way?

Answer (score 18):

You can send a `Home` key event via `adb`, pressing `Home` should put an Activity to the background:

> adb shell input keyevent 3

from the docs:

> public static final int KEYCODE_HOME Added in API level 1
>
> Key code constant: Home key. This key is handled by the framework and
>   is never delivered to applications. Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)

possible values: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

more to-the-point list:
[ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7789826/611007)

Comment: if it counts (in addition to the upvote), I believe your solution is good. It is closer to what the question asks than the accepted answer.

Comment: @shalafi (I normally don't comment like this but) thanks man I'm glad if it's useful to you!

Answer (score 1):

I use `appium_lib`and I write `background_app 8` to minimize and have the application running in the background. 8 is the number of seconds you will want to keep it minimized.