# Is there an ADB command to enable/disable mobile data?(Rooted Device)

Tags: android, testing, scripting, adb

I'm looking for an adb shell command to enable/disable mobile data. The app is only being tested on rooted devices so I have adb root privileges. I looked around and found that wifi can be enabled/disabled with:

```
$ adb shell svc wifi enable
$ adb shell svc wifi disable
```

These work for me but I wasn't able to find anything for mobile data.

Any reference to a list of adb shell svc commands that can be performed would be appreciated as well. I know there's a list of key input commands from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events) and obviously I'm aware of the [developer page](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) but there's no mention of svc.

Lastly, what is svc?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

To enable mobile data:

```
$ adb shell svc data enable
```

To disable mobile data:

```
$ adb shell svc data disable
```

Comment: If you run this command directly from shell or through terminal emulator you will need to get root privileges first with `su` command.

Comment: @bizzz any tips on how to install `su`?

Comment: @sdgfsdh that can be a smooth or not so smooth process, depends on your phone really. Google something like your phone model + "root and install su" for instructions

Comment: Works perfectly on 8.0, but doesn't work on 5.0 lollipop and previous versions. Do you have any idea, how can I fix it?

Comment: @AlexanderMarochko did you find the solution in 5.0 or previous versions.

Comment: @FatihTAN as far as i remember, it worked better to me via

`adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0`
and
`adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE` 

but finally on pre-lollipop devices i used Automate app, that was enough for my purposes

Comment: @Patrick were you able to find the meaning for `SVC`? Using `SVC` to turn on/ wifi and Mobile data works for me with my Android 8. While trying to research the `SVC` command on my own, I wasn't sure if this feature is deprecated or not or what the acronym stands for. I've tried looking, but there wasn't much on topic. Using an adb command: `adb -s <device udid> shell am broadcast -a io.appium.settings.data_connection -n io.appium.settings/.receivers.DataConnectionSettingReceiver --es setstatus <disable or enable>` doesn't have any affect on my device, (regarding Mobile Data, works with WiFi.)

Comment: @InvisibleExo I still don't know what it stands for but I do know it's responsible for accessing the data, power, and usb functionality. All svc commands (that I've found thus far) start with `svc data`, `svc wifi`, `svc power`, `svc usb`.

Comment: @Patrick, yeah its got a few more features if you run `svc` without additional arguments or use `help` such as bluetooth, though doesn't seem responsive with my device and nfc. I wanted to know more to help my decision where to use those commands in my code since they actually work. I tried looking at the offical android studio for any mention with adb commands, but haven't found any mention.

Comment: Found this post while still investigating the topic about `SVC` is doing. Link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later)