# How to toggle turn on/off mobile data with adb command

Tags: android, adb

I looking for toggle my android phone mobile data with adb command. that is usually i do it with touch my mobile data icon in [settings](https://postimg.org/image/nyxf0c7mz/).

i found many reference to do it, for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528824/is-there-an-adb-command-to-enable-disable-mobile-datarooted-device?newreg=71944a4e173a4bbdbe593576964557ea#) , but nothing work for me, i try use:

```
$ adb shell svc data enable
$ adb shell svc data disable
```

when i look to my android phone nothing happen. 
my android is KitKat 4 and i sure have rooted
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an ADB command to enable/disable mobile data?(Rooted Device)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528824/is-there-an-adb-command-to-enable-disable-mobile-datarooted-device)

Comment: i already explain i follow that sample and not working for me. thanks