# how to instrumentation test with location enabled in one test and disabled in the second test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium, android-uiautomator

I´m making an Android app.

So I´m starting with some instrumentation testing where I want to start with data enabled and location disabled and I want to test that a dialog asking me to enable location appears.

For my second test I want to start with data disabled and location enabled and I want to test that a dialog asking me to enable data appears.

How can I manipulate the location and data for an instrumentation test?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you do separation of the concerns then you have special class or classes for checking if some user settings are enabled/disabled. So you can mock it in test and check that dialogues are shown.

However, to test the class that checks user settings you need to manipulate with emulator/device directly. Check [Is there an ADB command to enable/disable mobile data?(Rooted Device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528824/is-there-an-adb-command-to-enable-disable-mobile-datarooted-device) or https://github.com/linkedin/test-butler