# How to disconnect Internet from appium Python

Tags: python-3.x, appium-android

I am doing Appium Automation in "Python", I need to ask, what is the method, which can disconnect the internet of mobile device via appium.
In Python.
and Also do share with me, how can I connect the disconnect Internet as well.

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody still looking for the answer - this is what worked out for me:

```
self.driver.open_notifications()
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.Switch[@content-desc="Airplane mode"]').click()
self.driver.back()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mobile device can be getting Internet/packet data through cellular network(e.g. 3G/4G) and WiFi both, one way to completely disconnect Internet can be to put the device in to Airplane/Flight mode.

This can be done through Appium by launching settings Activity and by toggling the Flight mode button.

On my Android S2 tab Settings Activity(`com.android.settings.Settings`) is under `com.android.settings package`.

You can trigger adb commands through Python `subprocess` library as well to disable and enable wifi and mobile data. Following SO post is having details of these adb commands:

[Is there an ADB command to enable/disable mobile data?(Rooted Device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528824/is-there-an-adb-command-to-enable-disable-mobile-datarooted-device)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it.

1. Toggle the mobile data on/off button by opening the data usage settings  page using adb command.

You need to find appPackage and appActivity of data usage page

[how to get appPackage and appActivity by adb](https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/11/09/adb/)

2. There is inbuilt library for device having Android version <=6  to enable disable airplane mode.

In robotframework it is called **Set Network connection status**

In python it would be similar I guess, just check.

For Android version > 6, there is no library to do the task, you need to toggle as you are doing for mobile data