# Calabash 'send_key_enter' is deprecated, how to replace it?

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

The `perform_action('send_key_enter')` is deprecated as other commands in [this list](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/deprecated_actions.map).

How can I replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is can be done with ADB commands.

system("#{default_device.adb_command} shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER")

You can see this reply in a question similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25089630/1165581 by [lux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894065/lux)