# Android ADB: Simulate Recent App key press

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to get the use ADB to simulate a Recent App key press?  I do not see it in the list of [assigned keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events) and I am not able to select it using `adb input shell tap` despite getting the coordinates from the debugging options.

I am trying to automate a task on my own personal phone (Nexus 5 with soft keys) so any hacky way is fine, assuming there is not a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*See @SimonMarquis answer below*

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
```

---

*(OBSOLETE)*

I don't think there is a keycode for it.

However, I **am** able to open the recent apps menu with `adb shell input tap` (testing on a Nexus 5 with Lollipop). For example:

```
adb shell input tap 800 1890
```

Comment: That did it.  I was working in Landscape for my other coordinates - I had my x's and y's mixed up when I got back to the home screen.

Comment: Too specific to physical devices and even OSs. @SimpnMarquis' solution is universal.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero Agreed, didn't know about it at the time. Cannot delete the answer while it's accepted though :/

Comment: Maybe @UserIsStuck can accept the other? Until then I think your edit will do :)

Answer (score 31):

The solution is to use the `KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH` KeyEvent:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
```

Still works, you don't even have to put its numeric value (187) into the command.