# Migrated to Android Studio: Where are the hardware buttons in the emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just migrated my projects and development to Android Studio. Even though I prefer to use hardware devices for development/testing sometimes I use the emulator. On Android studio I cannot find the option to enable the hardware keys on the device! How can I press now the power button/volume buttons, home/back/menu buttons?

I  have already tried creating a new device and enabling the hardware keys on the device settings. But I do not get them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Quick tipp: Use Genymotion instead of the default Emulator, it's way faster and has more features.

Comment: I am really happy with the speed of my default emulator (good PC). But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Genymotion is a good emulator but all the good things are available in paid version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure about making the buttons show up on the UI, but you can use ADB to send key events to your device.

for example: `adb shell input keyevent 3` is equivalent to clicking the home button.

For a complete list of valid key codes check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events) to another question.