# How to lock genymotion?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion

Is there anyway to lock genymotion emulator?

To test new notifications in Android 5.0, lollipop, I need to lock the Genymotion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question turns out to be useless. I would delete this, but I am not allowed to do so because, this question already has an answer.

Sorry

**I just had to click on power button twice.**

[image]

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize that there is a power button

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov you still have problem? By the way, it should not depend on the android version though

Comment: @Nabin yes, screen does not go black , it stays same

Answer (score 6):

go to `settings>security>screen lock` and set it to `swipe`. then press the power button twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `adb shell input keyevent 26`. That should emulate a power button press. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events) for more information. Of course you need to do `adb connect [device id]` first.

Comment: Thank you, having a look at

Comment: Does that even work on personal edition of genymotion?

Comment: I have no idea. Try it out. Dont see why it wouldn't

Comment: Also make sure that the lock screen is disabled in the emulation options.

Comment: @TameHog worked for me on API 19 device , on API 21+ devices it doesn't work...
Tried it on real device with API 21, worked like with no problems

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple.

Just press the power button twice in genymotion to lock the screen of emulator.
You can also lock the Android Emulator in same way by just clicking the power button twice.