# Genymotion: Cannot lock emulator

Tags: genymotion

I am using the Genymotion emulator and am unable to lock the screen by using the power button, or any of the other suggestions provided here: [How to lock genymotion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292060/how-to-lock-genymotion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the device go to Settings > Security > Screen Security and check that Screen Lock isn't set to None

Hope that helps!