# GamePad or remote control in android tv emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tv

In android studio when launching my app in the emulator, are there any way in order to show the gamepad or tv remote control in this emulator, in order to test properly my game?

Answer (score 9):

After the emulator load - just click on the 3 dots button at the bottom in the side panel.
Choose "Directional Pad" - and the remote is there.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try sending key events from command line
`adb shell input keyevent`

`usage: input [text|keyevent]
  input text <string>
  input keyevent <event_code>`

Here you can find more details
[ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)