# Tapping in the centre of screen for Camera App Android

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I got one scenario where I need to tap on the screen to take a photo in Samsung Note device. Can someone provide me an idea like how can I perform single tap in the centre of the screen.

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: haha, @MadPhysicist, and where he has to put it, can you elaborate? :)

Comment: @Farside Hmm. You could write a program to figure that out...

Comment: @MadPhysicist - awesome idea :P

Answer (score 0):

Well i took the centre , x and y coordinate of the entire screen and tapped , it worked fine.

```
            int startx, int starty;
    Point p = entireLayout.getCenter();
            startx = p.getX();
            starty = p.getY();
            starty = p.getY() + (p.getY()) / 2;
            getDriver().tap(1, startx, starty, 3000);
```

Comment: So you basically didn't bother trying anything, posted a vague question, then answered it once you tried the first obvious solution? This is why I voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

1. What you might be looking for is probably an appropriate way of doing it in all resolution devices using :

   public static final int KEYCODE_CAMERA // constant value 27

One way of sending it to the device is :

```
adb shell input keyevent 27
```

further details over this could be found on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_CAMERA) and [SO-7789826](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)

2. Another way of doing it would be accessing the **capture button** of the camera(using any possible locator strategy) and performing a `.click()` on it.

Comment: Thats is the issue , appium inspector or UI automator does not inspect the capture button at all.

Comment: probably the camera activity is not allowed to be debugged, but still adb commands could be send over