# Tell Smartphone to send SMS with PC

Tags: android, .net, windows, sms

Is there a way to do the following instructions using Android on phone and Windows on computer?

1. Computer: Reads numbers and meeting-dates out of a database.
2. Computer: Connects to the smartphone (via USB?) and uses its "send SMS"-function
3. Smartphone: Sends SMS with given Text.

---

Or do i have to use Third Party Email to SMS tools? I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use USB debugging and some faked user input.

First, enable USB debugging. Depending on your Android version and device model, this may be either an option somewhere in the normal settings app or in the hidden [developer mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/) which you can access by tapping the build number under "Status" 7 times. Also, you may be asked to allow access from your computer the first time you try to do anything with this feature.

Then, download [ADB and any driver needed for your device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118#post48915118), if any. ADB is a command-line tool to send debugging commands to your device.

You can use `adb devices` in the console to see if things work - you should see your device listed.

The idea is now to start the SMS app with recipient and text already filled in (which is a supported action) and then fake the user clicking "Send". This is where the tricky part lies. Depending on your device, there can be different key input required than for mine, for example. Usually you will need to send one or more D-Pad presses plus "Enter" (yes this works even if the device doesn't have a D-Pad).

The commands you'll need:

- `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:<full phone number here> --es sms_body "<SMS text here>" --ez exit_on_sent true`
  This will open the SMS app with the values already filled in. Replace `<full phone number here>` with the phone number, and `<SMS text here>` with your text. If you need to use quotes inside the text, you have to escape them like `\"`.
- `adb shell input keyevent <id>`
  This will send a fake keypress. The possible IDs are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8483797/1871033). Particularly interesting are:
  `19`: D-Pad up
  `20`: D-Pad down
  `21`: D-Pad left
  `22`: D-Pad right
  `23`: D-Pad center
  `66`: Enter
  You will need to play with these. You probably need to send `22` or `20` to simulate a "right" or "down" press to focus the "Send" button followed by `23` or `66` to simulate a press on the D-Pad center or enter key to "click" the button.

So, for example, it could look like this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:+436501234567 --es sms_body "This is a test" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

This would open the SMS app with the number `+436501234567` and the text `This is a test` already filled in and then simulate the "down" key and the "enter" key.

Please give the whole thing some time. Add some delays (at least 1s) between each command.

Comment: Looks awesome, but quite complicated as well. I might give it a try, but my boss will have to allow me taking time for that first.

Comment: Don't worry, it's pretty straight-forward once you figured out the keyevents to send (and it'll probably be either 20+66 or 22+66). I just tried to explain it in detail, but in a nutshell all you need to do is install ADB+drivers, figure out the keyevents and then you have it.