# React Native Dev Menu on Android Nexus 5 Device

Tags: android, windows-10, react-native, nexus-5

I have a basic `react-native` app which I am running on a *real Nexus 5* and I cannot find a way to enable the developer menu which is present for `iOS` and emulated devices.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

> Method 1: Using adb reverse (recommended)
>   You can use this method if
>   your device is running Android 5.0 (Lollipop), it has USB debugging
>   enabled, and it is connected via USB to your development machine.
>
> Run the following in a command prompt:
>
> $ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 You can now use Reload JS from the
>   React Native in-app Developer menu without any additional
>   configuration.

When I run `react-native run-android` I see this line in the terminal

`Running adb -s 06adb216 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

But I see **NO** *React Native in-app Developer menu*

I am running:

```
Windows 10
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.42.0
```

My `index.android.js` file looks like this:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Welcome from './src/modules/onboarding/components/welcome';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('mobileapp', () => Welcome);
```

Comment: Just to be clear, also physically shaking your device doesn't bring up the menu?

Comment: Shaking the device does not produce a menu. I tried this a few times. I didn't think Nexus 5 supported this?

Comment: Could you please run this command
`adb shell input keyevent 82` , this should work

Comment: @DurgaprasadBudhwani that works! Brings up the menu with all expected options. If you want to write up an answer, with some info on why this works, and a link to a doc which explains this part of `adb`, I can accept it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To work with android device or simulator without directly accessing hardware or click event, you can pass input to the device by `adb`
By `adb shell input keyevent`, either an `event_code` or a `string` will be sent to the device.

More information is given at [Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) or [ADB shell input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)

To open menu control, please use `adb shell input keyevent 82` command.

Please let me know if you need more information on this.

Regards,
Durga

Comment: adb shell input keyevent 82 , not responding in lollipop device