# Android Disable HDMI CEC control

Tags: android, adb, hdmi-cec

How I can switch off HDMI CEC control via `adb` shell ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
adb shell settings put global hdmi_control_enabled 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can emulate key press sequences for `Menu-> ... ->CEC Control menu item` selection exactly for your device using:

```
adb shell input keyevent <key_event_code_for_menu>
adb shell input keyevent <key_event_code_for_down>
etc.
```

and, for example `.bat` file. Key event codes you can get from [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html). Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969112/6950238) answer of [Rene Barbosa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4106703/rene-barbosa).