# Type with my physical keyboard on android while debugging

Tags: android, android-studio

I'd like to know if you have any references or tips to debug faster on real Android devices. I have a set of bash scripts to iterate rapidly over builds and signals, but sadly i waste a lot of time testing text inputs. I could hard-code but I am looking for a solution that is more universal between teams and projects. Typing directly on the device I am debugging would save me tons of time.

Do you know a way to achieve this using any tool or app?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go

Comment: not really, I am using virtual OTG (synergy project) for my workspace, I don't have physical ones to try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some answers here partially solve my current answer:

[ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)

I guess we could create a software utility on a terminal to write from there to the phone and then we'd be done.