# Can I select item from system dialog programmatically (root)?

Tags: android

I can open "Use USB to" system dialog by:

```
val p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"))
val stdout = DataOutputStream(p.outputStream)
stdout.writeBytes("am start com.android.settings/.UsbSettings")
stdout.flush()
stdout.close()
```

I also would like to select any of choice programmatically (for example "Transfer files")?

Is this possible with rooted Android?

[image]

**Update**

Seems I can play with `input keyevent` https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969112/9766649 (e.g. `61 --> "KEYCODE_TAB"` and `62 -->  "KEYCODE_SPACE"` are useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

For example to select fourth item ("Charge this phone") from dialog:

```
val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"))
val stream = DataOutputStream(process.outputStream)
stream.writeBytes("am start com.android.settings/.UsbSettings\n")
stream.writeBytes("input keyevent 21\n") // KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT
stream.writeBytes("input keyevent 20\n") // KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN
stream.writeBytes("input keyevent 20\n") // KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN
stream.writeBytes("input keyevent 20\n") // KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN
stream.writeBytes("input keyevent 66\n") // KEYCODE_ENTER
stream.flush()
stream.close()
```

(to select first item, just delete all lines with `KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN`)