# How to press the 'Done' key in virtual board in android devices by using appium and python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, keypress, appium-android

Hi I want to click on 'Done' button in the virtual keyboard on android devices.
Here i am entering an password in the devices after that i have to press 'Done' key in the virtual keyboard to proceed further.

Is there any way to do this by using Python 2.7 and appium?

Answer (score 0):

ADB commands should work example...'adb shell input keyevent 66'

Essentially, you can use adb to interact with the phone and send keys. See if ENTER works and then just use that.

Good answer here....[ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)

Comment: it's not working with any event code. In the android phone dial pad i have to click on "Done" button?

Comment: So your phone is connected to your PC/Mac. When the application is open can you use your keyboard to interact with the phone to enter the username/password?

Answer (score 0):

The simple of it, you just use:

```
Press Keycode       66
```

[here you can find some more event code.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: it's not working with any event code. In the android phone dial pad i have to click on "Done" button?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Do you have another solution?

Comment: @Danny  try to use /n after your text input

Answer (score 0):

Use `adb shell input keyevent 4` 
to close the keyboard and then use 
`adb shell input keyevent 66`  to press the enter key