# ADB command to open the all apps menu

Tags: android, adb

I've been searching a lot for a command in ADB to open the phone menu where all the apps are shown. I tried with the "KEYCODE_MENU" but then I found that this keycode is for something else.

Is there like a key event to do this? or I have to do it with a swipe up from the home screen?

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/ctrl-freak/9abb5aea0d89d7bd9df6a3d0ac08b73c

You need code for home button which is 3 so

```
adb shell input keyevent 3
```

Related [ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)