# Sending numbers as text via adb command to Android TV Box

Tags: adb

I am automating a test for an Android TV Box in which it is required to type out the name of certain VOD asset to watch. I am using `adb shell input text <string>` for that and it's working beautifully.
The issue comes when I try to input a number, the device considers it as if I'm changing channels, and it exits my search whenever I send a number. Does anyone know how to go around that?

Edit: the product owner confirmed that sending integers as text without having the box interpreting them as channel change is inevitable, and so I should close this question.

Comment: Please post the error you are getting in the question.

Comment: So if you execute `adb shell input text 1` the TV box interprets it as if the button 1 was pressed on the remote?

Comment: @shehanpathirathna there is no error. Robert nailed it. I tried even sending `adb shell input text "1"` to specify it is a string, but it's always interpreted as if I am changing channels.

Comment: Try https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/simple-input-text.py which can handle cases `input text` can't, and may work for yours too.

Comment: This can also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71367206/236465

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I couldn't make that work, I'm sorry

Comment: @MajdFreigi perhaps if you add details of what's not working to the question we may help

Comment: Never mind the question, I asked the product owner and they confirmed that it was not possible to send integers as text without the box interpreting those as channels.