# Is there a way to send an Emoji via ADB similar to ADB Shell input <text>

Tags: android, shell, command-line, adb

So I am using windows Shell Pipe commands to control an android virtual phone (MEmu). I want to be able to send both Emoji and text to any input text box on the android emulator. Sending plain text is fine using:

```
ADB Shell input <text>
```

The issue however is that I have no way of sending Emojis such as

I have spent many hours trying to figure it out but to no avail. Is this even possible or do I need to write a shell script/function that adb can trigger a system wide command to print said Emoji?

Kind regards,

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: [adb shell input unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14224549/295004)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71367206/236465