# Sending WhatsApp message in Hebrew through python with ADB (android)

Tags: python, android, encoding, adb, whatsapp

I succeeded to send the message in English, but with Hebrew it raises an error.
I checked also with the default sms app on my android phone and it works fine with Hebrew.
This is my code:

```
import subprocess
import time


def run_adb_command(command):
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True, encoding='utf-8')


def open_whatsapp_with_message(code, number, message):
    url = f'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={code}{number}'
    command = f'adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "{url}"'
    run_adb_command(command)
    time.sleep(3)

    input_command = f'adb shell input text "{message}"'
    print(input_command)
    run_adb_command(input_command)
    time.sleep(1)

    keyevent_command = 'adb shell input keyevent'
    run_adb_command(f'{keyevent_command} 21')
    run_adb_command(f'{keyevent_command} 21')
    time.sleep(1)

    run_adb_command(f'{keyevent_command} 21')
    run_adb_command(f'{keyevent_command} 21')
    run_adb_command(f'{keyevent_command} 66')


def process_numbers(numbers):
    code = "+"
    message = "בדיקה"

    for number in numbers:
        open_whatsapp_with_message(code, number, message)
        time.sleep(5)  # Add a delay between each iteration


# Example usage
number_list = ["12345678", "87654321"]
process_numbers(number_list)
```

the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    at com.android.commands.input.Input$InputText.sendText(Input.java:168)
    at com.android.commands.input.Input$InputText.run(Input.java:140)
    at com.android.commands.input.Input.onRun(Input.java:107)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:60)
    at com.android.commands.input.Input.main(Input.java:71)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:409)
```

I cannot see any text in Hebrew that's written, its just jumping to the next contact on list.

Comment: See: [Typing on an Android Device straight from computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71367206/295004) and [adb shell input unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14224549/295004)

Comment: The chance for unicode text survive the "long travel" from python to the shell (what ever is actually used) into adb client to adb server and then to adb-daemon o the Android phone and there in the shell to the command and finally to the app is next to zero. I would try to cut down the distance by e.g. using `pure-python-adb`. That would reduce the pipe length and directly send the data from python to adb server on your PC.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I tried both methods and I still can't see the message.

Comment: @Robert I tried this also and it didn't work. if someone could try it and send here the working code ill be thankful

Comment: @eitan You should update your post with details about which methods were tried and what errors did you get.