# How can I use ADB shell to input text in a language other than English and also print a sentence in that language on an Android device?

Tags: android, shell, input, output, adb

How can I use ADB shell to input text in a language other than English and also print a sentence in that language on an Android device?
input
adb shell input text 'السلام'

output
java.lang.Exception: call killProcess callstack! pid=4398
Killed

unput
adb shell input text 'السلام'
output
java.lang.Exception: call killProcess callstack! pid=4398
Killed

Comment: See: [Typing on an Android Device straight from computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71367206/295004)

Comment: What terminal program (and which OS) do you use for executing the adb shell command? Based on it's used locale the non-ASCII characters might already be destroyed before they actually reach your Andrid device if your terminal and adb use a different encoding.